# Foundation abide specify parent for error

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

The following mark up works well:

```
                <div class="small-8 columns male-female-select">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="small-6 columns male-select">
                            <label>{{ 'MALE'|trans }}</label>
                            <select class="sel-box" data-abide-validator="checkMaleFemale" name="numberOfMales">
                                <option value="">0</option>
                                {% for i in 0..data.numberOfGuests %}
                                    <option value="{{ i }}">{{ i }}</option>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="small-6 columns female-select">
                            <label>{{ 'FEMALE'|trans }}</label>
                            <select class="sel-box" data-abide-validator="checkMaleFemale" name="numberOfFemales">
                                <option value="">0</option>
                                {% for i in 0..data.numberOfGuests %}
                                    <option value="{{ i }}">{{ i }}</option>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I have m own validation in the abide validator:

```
$(document).foundation({
    abide : {
        validators: {
            checkExpiry: function() {
                var expiry = {
                    month: $('[name="ccExpirationMonth"]').val(),
                    year: $('[name="ccExpirationYear"]').val()
                };
                var expiryDate = new Date(expiry.year, expiry.month, 1);
                if(expiryDate >= Date.now())
                {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            },
            checkMaleFemale: function(el, required, parent){
                var lastValue = parseInt($('.male-select option:last-child').val()),
                    warningGroupMax = 'warningGroupMax',
                    genderWrapper = $('.male-female-select'),
                    selectedValue = 'data-val',
                    dropDownMaleFemale = {
                        value1:0,
                        value2:0,
                        checkTotalSelected: function (){
                            return parseInt(this.value1)+parseInt(this.value2);
                        },
                        applyError:function(){
                            if (this.checkTotalSelected() > lastValue || this.checkTotalSelected() < lastValue){
                                return false;
                            }
                            else if(this.checkTotalSelected() == lastValue){
                                return true;
                            }
                        },
                        validationCheck:function(){
                            this.applyError();
                        }
                    };

                    var maleValue = $('[name="numberOfMales"]').val();
                    dropDownMaleFemale.value1 = maleValue;
                   //dropDownMaleFemale.validationCheck();



                    var femaleValue = $('[name="numberOfFemales"]').val();
                    dropDownMaleFemale.value2 = femaleValue;
                    return dropDownMaleFemale.applyError();

                /*
                    var maleValue = $('.male-select .selectboxit-text').attr(selectedValue);
                    dropDownMaleFemale.value1 = maleValue;
                   //dropDownMaleFemale.validationCheck();



                    var femaleValue = $('.female-select .selectboxit-text').attr(selectedValue);
                    dropDownMaleFemale.value2 = femaleValue;
                    return dropDownMaleFemale.applyError();
                    */

            }
        }
    }
});
```

Is there a way of specifying where the class error will be applied from foundation? 
As far as I know it gets applied on the first parent that it finds, is there a way of specifing something like you would in jQuery?

```
element.parent().parent()
```

Thanks

Comment: Dont you need to add a <small.error/> inside the html: http://goo.gl/m7Ba0X ?

Comment: nope as I have declared my own css for the error, all I need is to move the error class on '.male-female-select'